# C# utility class for to make the first letter upper case and trim an input string

Tags: c#, asp.net

My aim is to "Sanitize a string".

The class should do:

- trim an input
- make the first letter upper case.

Could you please tell me:

- Is there a way to better code it?
- Would it make sense to use a PARAMETER for a method like: CapitalizeFirstLetterTrim(string x)

  - when I initiate an object I need write a lot of code like below, any other way to make it shorter?

    ```
    UserInputSanitizer myInput = new UserInputSanitizer();
    myInput.Input = "            ciao world";
    string ouput = myInput.CapitalizeFirstLetterTrim();
    ```

Useful resource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx

----------- CLASS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace WebProject.Core.Utilities
{
    public class UserInputSanitizer
    {
        // Backing variables
        private string _input;
        // Properties
        public string Input
        {
            set { _input = value; }
        }
        private string _output;

        // Backing variables
        // Properties
        public string Output
        {
            get { return _output; }
        }

        public string CapitalizeFirstLetterTrim()
        {
            // Trim
            _input.Trim();
            // Make First letter UpperCase and the rest levae lower case
            _output = _input.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + _input.Substring(1);
            return Output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a better way to code it is to create a simple method. maybe an extension method. you do not need a whole class for that.

Comment: for me the code is fine, however, i'd use an extension method (new feature starting in .net 3.0) to make it more readable

public static string CapitalizeFirstLetterTrim(this string myString)

then you don't need a helper class, you just do

string test = "            ciao world";
test = test.CapitalizeFirstLetterTrim();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an extension method for the string class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WebProject.Core.Utilities
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string Sanitize(this string s)
        {
            //your code to sanitize your string, for example
            if(s == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
            var trimmed = input.Trim();
            return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(trimmed);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
string s = "    UnsanitizedString";
s = s.Sanitize();
```

Answer (score 8):

I think I would create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on string instead:

```
public static class MyStringExtensions{
    public static string Sanitize(this string input)
    {
        if(input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

        var trimmed = input.Trim();
        return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(trimmed);
    }
}
```

You would call the method like this:

```
var s = "  Unsanitized         ";
var sanitized = s.Sanitize();
```

Comment: hi, i really like ArgumentNullException but TextInfo.ToTitleCase() would allow string to be ONLY TITLE CASE like "Hello Word" but I would need just the First letter to be UPPER CASE thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use Extension Method to support your requirement

With extension methods , you can use method as if they are part of System.String class.

[See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: ah, I like the Extension Method idea. Completely forgot about that. :)

Comment: thanks for sure i will look at Extension Method. thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

I would make the class and methods static

```
namespace WebProject.Core.Utilities
    {
        public static class UserInputSanitizer
        {

            public static string CapitalizeFirstLetterTrim(string input)
            {
                // Trim
                input.Trim();
                // Make First letter UpperCase and the rest levae lower case
                return input.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + input.Substring(1);

            }

        }
    }
```

and then you would call it like this:

```
string ouput = UserInputSanitizer.CapitalizeFirstLetterTrim("            ciao world");
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a utility class, it may make more intuitive sense to write this as an extension method for `string` so you can just call it directly from the literal.  Much less overhead.